# which is correct "to be as flexible as possible" or just "as flexible as possible"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, infinitives

On our website's homepage we have the following sentence:

> We make our software to be as flexible as possible so you can maintain and visualize the data that is important to YOU.

One of my friends insists it should be:

> We make our software as flexible as possible so you can maintain and visualize the data that is important to YOU.

Which one of these is grammatically correct and why? Are both wrong?

In case anyone's interested, our beta homepage is http://intellectpersonified.com/

Comment: #2 is correct, but I don't know why that is. However, if you use "want" instead of "make", #1 would be correct.

Comment: I will add that CAPS ON THE INTERNET MEAN SHOUTING. As your prospective customer, I don't want YOU to shout at ME. Use *italics* for emphasis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the grammatical rules, but your friend is right in terms of style. 1) definitely reads like it was literally translated from another language.

Answer (score 1):

Both look correct to me, though the first is rather stilted.  (Unnecessary words are usually poor style, too.)

Comment: I guess in this case it is better "not to be" :)

Comment: @Basarat Ali: Thwack. <-- my standard response to all things pun-like.

Comment: @Martha Rofl! lol <-- to fill the remainder characters.

Comment: Henry is spot-on- the first isn't exactly wrong, it's just that the second reads more easily because you've removed unnecessary words.  Unnecessary words are... not necessary.